# Error in Azure IoT hub Receiver

Tags: azure, iot

I copy pasted the code available in this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted/). I am able to get messages to IoT hub (the quota can show that). However, I am not receiving anything when I create the receiver.

Any thoughts?

Comment: for a simulator device (created using device explorer), used SSL the we could see messages in storage account, against yyyy/mm/dd directory. make sure you use ssl and port 1883 as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support

Answer (score 0):

Did you start with registering the devices (identity)? Did you specify the same deviceKey/deviceId in sender as in the receiver?

The link you provided is missing with a lot of code needed to connect two devices with send\receive behavior (or cloud -> device).

Comment: Yes I did. The device ID is the same also in both sender & receiver. Do you have a link for a complete code? Thank you

Comment: I don't have to code any more, but I implemented it basing on the link you provided and couple of next texts referred inside.(the first one is just a starter).

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the receive method is timing out due to no messages being present for the partition requested. Do you have the correct partition specified?

I had a similar issue in some code today because I stated the wrong partition identifier.

Comment: I resolved the issue.. I was using the latest version of the the Device library. When i used  3.0.3 everything worked fine.